# Assigning to 'readonly' return result

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to reset the state of this statement:

```
[[IAPManager sharedInstance]isProductPurchased:kInAppItem] = FALSE;
```

However, i'm getting the error of "Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C message not allowed". How do i reset the state of this statement?

In IAPManager.m

```
-(BOOL)isProductPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier
 {    
   return [_purchasedProducts containsObject:productIdentifier];
 }
```

Comment: Do you have access to the IAPManager code?

Comment: I'm pretty confused by what you're trying to do here. It's clear you're trying to assign the result of a statement. But even if you could assign it, I don't think it would have the result you're looking for. Can you give us the `isProductPurchased` function decleration?

Comment: Updated. The reason i'm trying to reset the purchase state is to enable the item to be purchased again. Is there a way to reset it?

Answer (score 1):

Your left hand side is a method invocation that returns a BOOL, it is not a reference to the property itself, so you cannot assign a value.

You need to refer to the code for `IAPPurchase`, but if it [this library](https://github.com/mruegenberg/IAPManager/blob/master/IAPManager.m) then there is no method to reset the purchased state for a product.

You can delete the app or delete the plist the library uses to store purchase data (by the way, this isn't a very secure way of recording in-app purchases)

Comment: If a product is purchased, how do i enable it to be purchased again?

Comment: Is it possible to create a method to reset the purchase state if there is none?

Comment: You could create a method to delete the plist file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a value to a return value of a method in Objective-C. You may be confused by the syntax

```
myObject.myProperty = myValue;
```

This sets the value of myProperty to myValue, but in doing so it essentially calls this method:

```
[myObject setMyProperty:myValue];
```

Either way, the left side of your code will be handled as a return value, not a property. Therefore you can't assign it.

If there exists a method like `setProductPurchased:` or `setIsProductPurchased:`, you need to call that like the second example. Otherwise there isn't a way to set the property, so you may have to set an instance variable directly.

Comment: How to set an instance variable directly?

Comment: Your updated code indicates that there is no variable for the product being purchased- it checks whether the purchased products includes the desired product. So what you need to do is add a method for `setProduct:purchased:` in which you add the product to the purchasedProducts array if purchased is TRUE, and remove it if purchased is FALSE.